# how to retrieve steps count from a bluetooth smart watch

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

I have a smartwatch from fireboltt and I want to retrieve step count into my app. I was able to retrieve heart rate, battery level, blood oxygen(spo2) but step count and temperature is still not working. If anybody has any idea to do it, please do share

Answer (score 1):

[Running Speed and Cadence Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/running-speed-and-cadence-service-1-0/) has `Instantaneous Stride Length` and `Total Distance` fields, which can be used to calculate step count.